# Use a function for multiple events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs tag, each with a button inside. Clicking on each button will show a hidden div tag.

```html
<div class="box-form">
    <label class="control-label">name : </label>
    <span class="text text-info txt_modelname">@Model.Name</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit__field">edit</button><br />
    <div class="box-edit-name" style="display:none;">
        <form id="Frm_EditName" class="frm" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control input-name" />
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success js-btn_submitname mt-1" disabled />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box-form">
    <label class="control-label">family : </label>
    <span class="text text-info txt_modelname">@Model.family</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit__field">edit</button><br />
    <div class="box-edit-name" style="display:none;">
        <form id="Frm_EditName" class="frm" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control input-name" />
                <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success js-btn_submitname mt-1" disabled />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create a function that displays every button on this div below it

```js
Btn_editName.click(function () {
    $('.box-edit-name').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the corresponding div via:

```
$("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.edit__field").click(function(){
  $(this).next().next().toggle()
})
```

You use two `.next()` calls because the div comes after a `<br />`

```js
$("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.edit__field").click(function() {
  $(this).next().next().toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-form">
  <label class="control-label">name : </label>
  <span class="text text-info txt_modelname">@Model.Name</span>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit__field">edit</button><br />
  <div class="box-edit-name" style="display:none;">
    <form id="Frm_EditName" class="frm" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control input-name" />
        <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success js-btn_submitname mt-1" disabled />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-form">
  <label class="control-label">family : </label>
  <span class="text text-info txt_modelname">@Model.family</span>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit__field">edit</button><br />
  <div class="box-edit-name" style="display:none;">
    <form id="Frm_EditName" class="frm" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control input-name" />
        <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success js-btn_submitname mt-1" disabled />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I use the next 6 if I have 6 div tags?

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy I don't understand what you mean by 6 div tags

Comment: The same number of div that is repeated

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy It depends on the HTML structure but potentially yes, that would work.